# Doctrine2: Dependency graph for a set of entities

Tags: php, symfony, sorting, doctrine-orm

Using Symfony and Doctrine, I’m writing a component that populates the database with entries of arbitrary entities during the deployment of an application.

I want to make this component generic, so I’m trying to resolve dependencies between entities automatically and insert them in the correct order.

I am currently get the dependencies of each single entity through the entity metadata, recursively:

```
public function getEntityDeps($eName)
{
    $deps = [];

    foreach ($this->entityManager->getClassMetadata($eName)->getAssociationMappings() as $mapping)
    {
        $deps[] = $mapping['targetEntity'];
        $deps = array_merge($deps, $this->getEntityDeps($mapping['targetEntity']));
    }

    return $deps;
}
```

The result is obviously a list of the following kind:

```
// NOTE: The real list of course contains class names instead of entity aliases.
[
    "FooBundle:EntityA" => [],
    "FooBundle:EntityB" => ["FooBundle:EntityA", "FooBundle:EntityC"],
    "FooBundle:EntityC" => ["FooBundle:EntityA"],
    "BarBundle:EntityA" => ["BarBundle:EntityB"],
    "BarBundle:EntityB" => []
]
```

The next step would be apply some type of topological sorting to the list, I guess.

However, I’m not sure if I can use a generic algorithm here or if I’m forgetting something. Especially as entities are not necessarily related (so that, in fact, we may have more than one dependency graph).

Also, I’d hope that there’s some internal Doctrine functionality which can do the sorting for me.

So what would be the most reliable way to sort an arbitrary set of Doctrine entities? Is there some reusable Doctrine feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after digging through the Doctrine source code for a while, I found that they have indeed an implementation of topological sorting (DFS for that matter). It's implemented in `Doctrine\ORM\Internal\CommitOrderCalculator`.

And where is this `CommitOrderCalculator` used? In `UnitOfWork`, of course.

So, instead of manually calculating the correct commit order, I just needed … to move the call to `$em->flush()` outside the `foreach` loop that went through the entities and let UOW do the work itself.

Duh.